# Constructing an UPDATE .. SET .. WHERE .. statement with SQLAalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have two lists of column names: `setcols` and `wherecols`. I want to build a query with SQLAlchemy methods that is along the lines of

```
UPDATE tablename SET setcols[0]= ?, ... WHERE wherecols[0]= ?, ...
```

What I tried is

```
t = sa.table('tablename', *[sa.column(name) for name in setcols+wherecols])

query = t.update(). \
        where(t.c[cn] == sa.bindparam(cn) for cn in wherecols).\
        values({cn: sa.bindparam(cn) for cn in setcols})
```

and this

```
query = t.update({cn: sa.bindparam(cn) for cn in setcols}). \
        where(t.c[cn] == sa.bindparam(cn) for cn in wherecols)
```

but neither of these worked and I got the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: SQL expression object or string expected, got object of type <class 'generator'> instead
```

I've read the manual and thought that the values to be set can be provided as a dictionary, but I see that I'm wrong...

Could anyone help?

I'm using sqlalchemy-1.1.13.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in the way you call [`where()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Select.where). It expects a `whereclause`, not a generator object. Combine those generated predicates using for example `and_` or `or_`:

```
query = t.update(). \
        where(and_(*[t.c[cn] == sa.bindparam(cn) for cn in wherecols])).\
        values({cn: sa.bindparam(cn) for cn in setcols})
```

Comment: Thanks, @Ilja! I think it's not the first time you're helping me out.It worked like a charm.

Comment: I am now getting an error `sqlalchemy.exc.CompileError: bindparam() name 'colum_in_wherecols' is reserved for automatic usage in the VALUES or SET clause of this insert/update statement.   Please use a name other than column name when using bindparam() with insert() or update() (for example, 'b_colum_in_wherecols').` Maybe you know what's going on? The name of this column was in the wherecols, so it was not mentioned in the `values()` method...

Comment: Forgot about that. Do as the exception instructs and for example prefix the bind param names used in the WHERE clause with `b_`, and use that same prefix when passing the arguments to `execute()`.

Comment: And also in that light you don't need the manual `values()` call that just "fixes" bind params (compared to literal values or SQL expressions), as SQLAlchemy does that for you automatically.